How to filter Django JSON field in Postgres?
json content: "{\"title\": {\"value\": \"dene\", \"type\": null}, \"description\": {\"value\": \"desc\", \"type\": null}, \"detay\": {\"value\": \"det\", \"type\": \"text\"}, \"tarih\": {\"value\": \"2024-05-02\", \"type\": \"date\"}}"
I want to filter content__title__value = 'dene'
I tried this code block objects.filter(content__title__value='dene'). In this case, it returns an empty array.

check the format its in string or json format, when got data through query in Django views , it wont directly support as json , either , we need to rewrite to json format in backend , or to convert to json format

Please editors do not remove the tag postgresql. Not all SQL databases handle JSON the same way. If there is any tag that should be removed here, it is django-views.

Does this help?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
